# How to query certain elements of an array of objects? (mongodb)

Tags: mongodb

say I have a mongo DB collection with records as follows:

```
{
email: "person1@gmail.com",
plans: [
         {planName: "plan1", dataValue = 100},
         {planName: "plan2", dataValue = 50}
       ]
},
{
email: "person2@gmail.com",
plans: [
         {planName: "plan3", dataValue = 25},
         {planName: "plan4", dataValue = 12.5}
       ]
}
```

and I want to query such that **only** the **dataValue** returns where the email is "person1@gmail.com" and the planName is "plan1". How would I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/#aggregation-pipeline).

The pipeline may look like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "email" :"person1@gmail.com", "plans.planName": "plan1" }},
  { $unwind: "$plans" },
  { $match: { "plans.planName": "plan1" }},
  { $project: { "_id": 0, "dataValue": "$plans.dataValue" }}
])
```

The first [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage will retrieve documents where the `email` field is equal to `person1@gmail.com` and any of the elements in the `plans` array has a `planName` equal to `plan1`.

The second [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage will output one document per element in the `plans` array. The `plans` field will now be an object containing a single plan object.

In the third `$match` stage, the unwound documents are further matched against to only include documents with a `plans.planName` of `plan1`. Finally, the [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage excludes the `_id` field and projects a single `dataValue` field with a value of `plans.dataValue`.

Note that with this approach, if the `email` field is not unique you may have multiple documents consist with just a `dataValue` field.